# Reinforcement learning : Neural Net

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning

While use a neural net to obtain generalization in high state spaces, what are the input units?

For example if the state vector is 1 dimensional, say position on the real  axis..there would only be one input unit? ( provided seperate network for each action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, at least if you are using an algorithm similar to Q-learning or Sarsa, where the function approximator should learn a Q-function `Q(s,a)` . In your case, if you employ one neural network per action, the network has to approximate the function `Q(s)` . And if, in addition, the state has dimensionality one, then the network will require only one input neuron.

Comment: What if we want the same neural net, each state will have its own action? but if certain actions are possible only in certain states what happens? the network is no longer fully connected?

Comment: I guess the simplest solution is to have a fully connected network, and if some combination of state-action is not possible, e.g., s0 and a2, the network simply will approximate Q(s0, a2) = 0 (assuming initial Q is zero and rewards are possitive). I mean, the policy never selects the action a2 in state s0.  Maybe, as you suggest, an ad-hoc network architecture may help, but I'm not sure.